# Getting an animation to fully play before a for loop proceeds (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, animation, for-loop

So, I'm working on a turn based game where there are friendly characters on the left and enemy characters on the right. The characters are looped through a for loop to determine actions/update health/etc.

```
public function onTurn() {
        for each (var i in charactersPlayer) {
            i.everyTurn();
        }
        for each (i in charactersOpponent) {
            i.everyTurn();
        }
        turn++;
}
```

My problem arises when I want to play an animation or halt the progression of the for loops (to let health bars animate). Ultimately I want each character to run their `everyTurn()` method one by one, and for the for loops to wait for a character to finish their animation before going on to the next iteration.

I have a method in the `Character` class (`charactersPlayer` and `charactersOpponent` are both containers for `Character` objects) `animationDone` which returns `false` if the animation is not done yet, and `true` if the animation is done.

All help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an asynchronous loop, instead of calling it all at once, you call one's `everyTurn()` and wait for him to dispatch an event (either `Event.COMPLETE` or any custom string), this will signify this character has finished its turn. You react on the event by finding the next character which should perform actions, and call its `everyTurn()`, and so on until a winning condition. Or, as you have a state check function, you can use an enter frame listener to do this trick.

```
var turn:int;
var currentlyActing:Character;
function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    // other enter frame code, if any
    if (currentlyActing.animationDone()) {
        currentlyActing=selectNext(currentlyActing);
        if (currentlyActing) currentlyActing.everyTurn();
    }
}
function selectNext(c:Character):Character {
    var i:int=charactersPlayer.indexOf(c);
    if (i>=0) {
        i++;
        if (i<charactersPlayer.length) return charactersPlayer[i];
        if (charactersOpponent.length>0)return charactersOpponent[0];
        // no opponents at this point. Process win
        processWin();
        return null; // game over
    }
    i=charactersOpponent.indexOf(c);
    if (i==-1) return null; // oops!
    i++;
    if (i<charactersOpponent.length) return charactersOpponent[i];
    if (charactersPlayer.length>0) return charactersPlayer[0];
    // no player chars left
    processLose();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Man, this is more complicated than I was hoping, but if it works, it works. I'll implement your solution tomorrow and let you know how it turns out!

Comment: I'm having some trouble, but it's in my implementation. No further questions; I can figure this out on my own! Thanks again.

Comment: Update: It definitely works. (Sorry for the late response) You can see it in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0QonjJMiSI

Comment: Nice, apparently you have used some of the graphics ideas from Sonny 2 ;)

Comment: Yeah I love Krin's work.
I traced the basic character model from Sonny, but am moving the game to be larger and more character based than Sonny was.

Also crafting, (more) open world travel, and character dialogue! :D